# Scrollviewer not scrolling without height

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, scrollviewer

I am writing a Windows Phone 8.1 app (WINRT).

I have implemented a **scrollviewer** in page. It contains a **stackpanel** having **richtextblock with long texts**, and a **button**.

But the problem is that this scrollviewer is **not scrolling** at all. If i am manually setting a **height** to this scrollviewer it is scrolling but it looks ugly on higher resolutions. How to make this scrollviewer work without having manual height to it.

```
<ScrollViewer Name="WhyJoin_User_Content_Scroll"
                              Margin="0,10,0,10" 
                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                              >
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <RichTextBlock Name="WhyJoin_User_Content_RichTextBlock"
                    FontWeight="Light"
                    Margin="20,10,20,0" 
                    Foreground="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_DarkBlueColor}"
                    FontSize="19"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                     TextAlignment="Justify">
        <RichTextBlock.Blocks>
            <Paragraph>
                <Paragraph.Inlines>
                    <Run Text=" Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text ">
                    </Paragraph.Inlines>
                </Paragraph>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph.Inlines>
                        <Run Text=" Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text ">
                        </Paragraph.Inlines>
                    </Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Paragraph.Inlines>
                            <Run Text=" Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text "></Run>
                        </Paragraph.Inlines>
                    </Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Paragraph.Inlines>
                            <Run Text=" Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text "></Run>
                        </Paragraph.Inlines>
                    </Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Paragraph.Inlines>
                            <Run Text="i: Practice work hours of experts"></Run>
                        </Paragraph.Inlines>
                    </Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Paragraph.Inlines>
                            <Run Text="ii: Address, Phone numbers etc."></Run>
                        </Paragraph.Inlines>
                    </Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Paragraph.Inlines>
                            <Run Text="iii: Appointment requests"></Run>
                        </Paragraph.Inlines>
                    </Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Paragraph.Inlines>
                            <Run Text=" Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text "></Run>
                        </Paragraph.Inlines>
                    </Paragraph>
                </RichTextBlock.Blocks>
            </RichTextBlock>
            <Button 
                        x:Name="ButtonWhyJoin_User_Register"    
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Width="150"   
                        Height="70"
                            Margin="0,10,0,0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"

                        Click="ButtonWhyJoin_User_Register_Click"
                        FontWeight="ExtraLight"
                        Background="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_DarkBlueColor}" 
                        BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleYesNo}"  
                        Foreground="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_BackgroundColor}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: As I've tried the above code - it works fine - if you copy and add more paragraphs, so that the text goes outside the view, then it's possible to scroll it with scrollviewer. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to bind the height and/or width of the scroll viewer to the ContentRoot. This is easiest done in Blend, by doing this whatever the screen resolution you will automatically achieve the desired height.

http://pho.to/8kh1T

This is what the XAML would look like

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ContentRoot}"/>
```